# How can I understand this example of Query taken from current Mathematica documentation?

Tags: query

```
Query[All, <|"A" -> "a", "B" -> "b", "C" -> "c"|>] @ {
  <|"a" -> 1, "b" -> "x", "c" -> {1}|>,
  <|"a" -> 2, "b" -> "y", "c" -> {2, 3}|>,
  <|"a" -> 3, "b" -> "z", "c" -> {3}|>,
  <|"a" -> 4, "b" -> "x", "c" -> {4, 5}|>,
  <|"a" -> 5, "b" -> "y", "c" -> {5, 6, 7}|>,
  <|"a" -> 6, "b" -> "z", "c" -> {}|>}
```

It renames all the column headers from lower-case letters to upper-case letters. And works. But the rules appear reversed to me, which means I'm not thinking about it right. See ref/Query in the Documentation Center for the source of this example. If I could understand this, I would understand Query better.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is "ascending" sub-query operator syntax.  It operates on the entire row to produce a new row with the specified keys and values as the operator applied to the row.

However, the operators in the sub-query are strings so [`Query`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Query.html) employs some *syntax sugar* to reduce the amount of code needed to be written.

So for

```
"A" -> "a"
```

`Query`'s *syntax sugar* "interprets" the operator not as `"a"` but as

```
GeneralUtilities`Slice["a"]
```

This is an internal function that when applied to the row the value associated with key `"a"` is returned.

```
GeneralUtilities`Slice["a"]@<|"a" -> 1, "b" -> "x", "c" -> {1}|>
```

> ```
> 1
> ```

This results in the keys being renamed in the association returned.

This is less verbose and some would say easier to read (once you know about the *syntax sugar*) than the alternative.  For example

```
Query[All, <|"A" -> #"a", "B" -> #"b", "C" -> #"c"|>&]
```

Also because [`&`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Function.html)'s operator precedence means that additional brackets often need to be included to prevent it from capturing the additional expressions when chaining operators together in `Query` with [`/*`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RightComposition.html).

Note that you can always view what `Query` will do with [`Normal`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Normal.html). Although it does not always return standard Wolfram Language functions; current case in point.

```
Query[All, <|"A" -> "a", "B" -> "b", "C" -> "c"|>] // Normal
```

> ```
> Map[
>  GeneralUtilities`ApplyThrough[
>   <|
>    "A" -> GeneralUtilities`Slice["a"],
>    "B" -> GeneralUtilities`Slice["b"],
>    "C" -> GeneralUtilities`Slice["c"]
>    |>
>   ]]
> ```

Hope this helps.